# php string with multiple delimiters to table

Tags: php, string, delimiter

Hello can you help me get this String

```
$string ="High School#Church Divinity School of the Pacific#1989 | University of California#1992  | University#California State University, Long Beach#1999";
```

to table (echo):

High School

Church Divinity School of the Pacific

1989

---

University of California

1992

---

University

California State University, Long Beach

1999

---

I already used array, explode and preg_split but i need help.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to add your code that isn't working, and explain what the problem with it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
$string ="High School#Church Divinity School of the Pacific#1989 | University of California#1992  | University#California State University, Long Beach#1999";
$string = str_replace(array('#', '|'), array('<br />', '<hr />'), $string);

echo $string;
?>
```

**CodePad**: http://codepad.org/Rrrue2aj

Comment: Sorry, if my question wasn't clear. I'm not an expert.
IT WORKS!!! you're my hero! Thank you.